# What is Mantra? What is the criteria by which a word turns into mantra?

Tags: mantras

Saying a mantra has energy inside can't be true as every word has energy within it. Then what's the criteria of Mantra? On what basis a word should be called Mantra?

Comment: मानने त्रायते इति मन्त्रः . This is the literal definition of mantra. Which protects when we chant it is called a mantra. A mantra has om and namah in it.

Comment: Good find. Let's wait for more. :)

Comment: I think When Devata sits in a word/sentence then that becomes Mantra of that Devata...

Comment: Yes. Seems, Deity is established.

Comment: It is something that is divined by a rishi.

Comment: Only Vedas have Mantras, other are shalokas.
Indeed Mantras are just thoughts.
When you do chant a Mantra, your mind gets focused (due to the rebervation of Aum) how ever it doesnot make any sense till the time you do not know the meaning and follow it in your daily life, So may be Sree charan is right as Vedic Mantras almost all have Aum in it **but not namah**

Comment: @SreeCharan Gayatri mantra is the most famous in Hindu's and it doesnot have namah in it

Comment: As we meditate on it, we call it as a mantra. We are invoking savita devata in the mantra. Aren't we? Gaatri is a meter.  @Rishi.  In anganyasa and karanyasa there are om and namah. I don't know we can relate it or not here.

Comment: @SreeCharan And why do you think a Meter can not contain Mantras?

Comment: @Rishi When did I say that meters can't have mantras? There are many gayatris, Rudra Gayatri, vishnu gayatri etc., we invoke that deity in that mantra in gayatri meter. .

Comment: What do we call Gayatri Mantra when one is not meditating on it? I also did not get your point of Namah in a mantra?

Comment: When no one meditates, and starts singing it loud, becomes a song and its power is compromised. So singing it loud  in tunes like  a movie song and keeping mantras as ringtones is not recommended.@Rishi

Answer (score 6):

According to Tantra, the Varnas(alphabets) are nothing but Matrikas(Deities related to Mother Goddess).

One meaning of Matrika is "one who creates".So, Matrika is nothing but Brahmarupini Shakti.And the Varnas are the Matrikas.And the reason for that is that Nada or sound is nothing but another form of Shakti.And,thus,we have,from अ(a)  to क्ष(kṣa) , the 50 Matrikas.

But,having said that, any such combinations of varnas or of words can not be technically called a Mantra as well.Because, all Mantras have to have the three limbs(Angas) viz-Devata,Rishi and Chandah.

**Devata**-The Deity who is being praised by the Mantra.

**Rishi**-The Seer to whom the Mantra was first revealed.From him only we all get to know the Mantra.

**Chandah**-The metre (like Gayatri,Nichruth Gayatri,Ushnik,Anshthupa etc) in which the Mantra is composed.

For example, for the Gayatri Mantra,the most famous among all Veda Mantras,the Rishi is Vishvamitra Gathinah , Devata is Savitr,Chandah is Nichruth Gayatri.

This is found in  the 62nd Sukta of the 3rd Mandala of Rig Veda(RV 3.62.10).
In Yajur Veda (Vajasaneyi Samhita 36.3 etc) the same Mantra is found with only difference being in the Chandah part, which is now Ushnik(comprised of 27 syllables ).

Next,take this rather popular Puranic Mantra ["Apavitrah Pavitrova.."](http://greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_vishnu-om_apavitrah_pavitro_va.php) ,which is found in more than one Puranas:

> ॐ अपवित्रः पवित्रो वा सर्वावस्थां गतोऽपि वा । यः स्मरेत्पुण्डरीकाक्षं
>   स बाह्याभ्यन्तरः शुचिः ॥
>
> Om Apavitrah Pavitro Vaa Sarva-Avasthaam Gato-[A]pi Vaa | Yah
>   Smaret-Punnddariikaakssam Sa Baahya-Abhyantarah Shucih ||

This is  a Mantra and not just a Sloka and the three limbs of it are as given below:

> [image]
>
> For this mantra,Vamdeva is the Rishi,Vishnu is the Devata,Gayatri is
>   the Chandah and internal purification(Hrudi Pavitrakarana) is the 
>   purpose for which it is chanted.

Similarly,for Tantrik Mantras(those found in the Agamas) there are additional limbs.They have six limbs(some even say seven but six is usually agreed upon ) viz-Rishi,Chandah,Devata,Beejam,Shakti and Keelakam.

As a typical example i can cite:

> For Kalimantra Rishi is Bhairava,Chandaha is Ushnik,Devata is
>   Kalika,Beejam is Hrim ,Shakti is Hum and Keelakam is Krim(also called the Adya
>   Beejam).

So,in a nutshell,all Mantras have to have at least the 3 aforementioned limbs to be technically called a Mantra.

Even,the Ekakshara Pranava(OM) has the following limbs:

> [image]
>
> For Omkara Brahma is the Rishi,Gayatri is the Chandah,Agni Paramatma
>   is the Devata,Suklo Varna,and it is to be invoked at the beginning of
>   all Karmas(Rituals).

A nirukta of Mantra(why it is so called) is found in the 17th chapter of the Kularnava Tantram and is as follows:

> MananAttatvasvarupasya DevvasyAmitatejasaha| TrAyate
>   sarvabhayatasmanmantra Ittiritaha ||
>
> By meditation, (**Man**ana), on the luminous Deity who is the form of
>   Truth ,it saves, (**tra**yate), from all fear; therefore it is called
>   mantra.
>
> **Kularnava Tantram, Chapter 17,Verse 54**

Comment: are Mantras both active and passive?

Comment: @Rohit Don't know what u exactly meant by that..but yes mantras can have as many as 60 doshas as per Tantra texts like Kularnava Tantram,Sharada Tilak etc..Few such Doshas are-Ruddha(blocked),Baddha(bounded),Kruddha(angry),Kumar,yuvak,Balak,Proura(aged) ,Andha(blind),Nirjeeva(inactive),Abhisapagrastha(cursed),Khandita(cut,broken),Angahina(without limbs),Supta(asleep) and so on..Its futile to do japa of any  such mantras..But there r prescribed methods too for purifying these mantras..Like the Dasavida Samskaras..

Comment: @Rickross some Veda mantras have ॐ but why Beeja is not included as limb?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Here Beejam (one of the 6 limbs of Tantrik mantra) is different ..it does not mean the beejas like Om.,Hrim, Haum etc..For eg as u can see from the example given that even Shakti(Hum) and Keelakam(Krim) are also one or the other Beejams..

Comment: @Rickross For Kalimantra i think kreeng is the beeja and hreem keelakam. kindly check

Comment: Okay I will chk @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: You mention a śloka which tells the 6 limbs of peaṇava. Could you please tell me the source it’s from ?

Comment: Let me see if the source scripture is mentioned or not .. I'll let you know @Bingming

Answer (score 2):

The
  first sutra  is  the  explanation
  of
 [mantra](http://abhidharma.ru/A/Simvol/Indyizm/Shiva-sutra/0004.pdf):

> 1. cittam     mantrah    //    (Shiva sutra 2.1)

Mind     is     mantra.

In  this  sutra,  there  are  two  understandings  of the  mind  and both are divine.  The  first understanding is that the mind is the thought  of  a  sacred  word.  The  second  understanding  is  that
mind is the thought of a  sacred aspirant who is treading on the 
sacred  path.

The  author  now  explains  this  sutra  in  these  two  ways.  The   word  "mind"  does  not mean  what we  ordinarily  understand  by   the  word  "mind."  Here,  the  word  mind  means  "that  by  which   you  become  aware  of supreme  consciousness." So  this  mind  issaid  to be that by which your self is exposed  in its  fullness.  It is vimarsa-  I  consciousness  -  thought  in  two  ways:  in prasada mantra and   in pranava   mantra.   Prasada   mantra is  "the  mantra  of external  flow."Pranava  mantrais  "the  mantra  of external  and  internal  flow."  It  is  the  internal  flow  in  the  external world  and  the  external  flow  in  the  internal  world.

So in both ways,  this  is  the  state  of  citta  (thought).  It is  said   to  be  mantra  because  it  is  secret   (guptam).   It  is  not  written,  it   lives  in  a  secret  world.  When  you  recite  this  mantra,  you  are   not  reciting  it with lips,  but with  consciousness.  When  you re-cite  and  you  are  aware   of  the  mantra,"of  its occurrence in your own  self, you  will understand that this whole universe  is  the  expansion  of yourself.  This  is  the  kind  of rise that  occurs  when  you  travel  from  the  internal  world  to  the  external  world.

So, it is said that this pranava  mantrais  truly  a  mantra,  for  the  word  "mantra"is  made   up   from manandtra.   Man from  the  word manana means  "causes  you  to  reside  in  your  own  God  consciousness."Tra from  the  word trana means  "protects you  from  all the  evils of the  world."So  when  you  focus  your  mind towards  God  con-sciousness,  you  are  protected  from  all  the horrors  of the  world.Here,  this  is the  meaning  of the  word "mantra."

Now  this  exposition  of mantra  is  explained  in  another  way.Because the mind of this yogi is always purified and never think sabsurd  thoughts,  thinking  only  divine  thoughts  and  being  focused towards  God consciousness, it is mantra. Whatever comes into  the  mind  of this  yogi  is  divine.  So,  all  of his  thoughts  are divine and hence,  his  thought  is  also mantra.

om padmni om

om nama  sivaya

svacchanda  bhairavaya  namah

These  sentences are  collections  of sacred  words.  Collections  of sacred  words  are  not mantras,  but just  a  waste  of time  for the aspirant.  In  a real sense, these  two  - the aspirant's mind and  a sacred  word  experienced   as prasada mantra   and/or pranav amantra  -  are  mantras.

The Sarvajnanottara also  explains  this  in  the  same  way.

> Those mantras which are recited with the lips and with the mindare not
>   really mantras.Devatas and Gandharvas,all these great- souls, have
>   deluded themselves in thinking that these are actually mantras.  And 
>   additionally,  they are  filled  with  tremendous pride  thinking that 
>   they  are  verbally reciting the  name  of God.(Sarvajnanottara16-17)

Those  so-called  mantras  are  not  actually  mantras.  Mantra  is divinity  in  the  mind  of the  yogi  or  the  flow  of subjective  God consciousness  towards  objective  God  consciousness  or  the  simultaneous  flow  of subjective  God  consciousness  towards  objective  God  consciousness,  and  the  flow  of objective  God  consciousness  towards  subjective  God  consciousness.

In  the Tantra  Sadbhava,

> this  same  thing  is  also  explained:The life of all mantras is
>   solely the energy of God consciousness.When  that  energy  is  absent,
>   all  those  collections  of words  are useless just  like  a  mass  of 
>   clouds  in  the  rain less  autumn  sky.(Tantra   Sadbhava)

In  the Srikanthi samhita     Sastra,

it  is  also  said:

> The  one  who  recites  mantra  for  the  sake  of realizing  God 
>   will never attain the reality of God consciousness.  There  is  only
>   one  thing that  a  yogi  must maintain  and that is  awareness, 
>   awareness  of the union  of objective  God  consciousness  with
>   subjective God consciousness and, in one driving push, the flow of
>   objective and  subjective  God  consciousness.

This  is  narrated  in Spanda

> in  this  verse:Because  these  words  are  digested  along  with  the
>   mind  of theaspirant, they are said to be, along with the divinity of
>   the yogi,one with  divine  God  consciousness.(Spanda  Karika2.2)

This is why Bhagavan Bhairava, Lord Śiva, has explained in Mālinīvijaya tantra that when meditation, or any practice, is done without the development of pramiti bhāva1, it becomes useless. So meditation should be done with the attachment of pramiti bhāva, there must be pramiti bhāva.

For instance there is mantra, “oṁ namaḥ śivāya,” it is to be repeated in continuity but not through your tongue, not through your words, it is to be repeated in awareness, in pramiti bhāva . . . what you are speaking. You must know what you are speaking. When you speak and you don’t know what you are speaking it is useless, that japa becomes useless.

But that first glow of that thought is subsided a little, a little, by and by, by and by, by and by. That should not take place. It must be just as fresh as it was at the first moment of practice. So you should do practice in such a way that the continuity of this production of sparks of the same thought should be as fresh as it was at the beginning point. You should not get stale.

So, the way of meditation is, just to meditate and hold the first freshness. And this first freshness must live in the cycle of these sparks, in the cycle of these sparks of this thought of meditation. The first fresh thought must pervade throughout, then your meditation is successful. Otherwise it is useless.

That is what he says, **in Mālinīvijaya Tantra Lord Śiva has said; tena guptena tena**, when it is locked, when it is subsided, when it is covered by other thoughts, other subsided thoughts, tena guptā, that pramiti bhāva is subsided, it subsides by and by; śeṣā varṇā then afterwards there are only letters and words and sentences.

Any thought will take you to the state of God consciousness; but there must be one thought and this first fresh thought, like that, in all the cycles of thought.

Speciality, that does not count, special thoughts only we produce in the beginning in disciples. Afterwards, when they have developed this strength of awareness of pramiti bhāva then it does not matter. You can give rise to any thought, any disgusted thought.

Thought becomes mantra. Because in each and every word there is the residence of God consciousness. God consciousness is residing in each and every action, each and every word; so it does not matter. In the beginning we produce mantras just to create faith in the devotee that, “I am reciting mantra of God!”

This is also mantra of God: “this is specs (spectacles, glasses), this is specs, this is specs.” When you say, “this is specs, this is specs,” just from the very [first} fresh point, [have] attentive awareness; it will carry you to God consciousness. And just embrace your girlfriend; while embracing your girlfriend it will carry you to God consciousness if you develop that awareness of pramiti bhāva there. It does not matter; mantras are not only mantras.

> It is said in the same Mālinīvijaya tantra:
>
> śloka ghatādi yatkiṁcit . . . /

You can do [it with] any topic, just discuss some points of your business, but there, if you maintain awareness and pramiti bhāva you will rise to God consciousness. You will not rise, you have not to rise; you’ll get establishment in that.

Establishment, you have not to get establishment also; it is there! It will appear. It will appear to you.

NB:  When there is objective state also attached to subjective state that is not pramiti bhāva, that is pramātṛi bhāva. And when that objective state is connected with cognitive state also that is pramāṇa bhāva. When that objective state is completely pure objective state that is prameya bhāva. And pramiti bhāva is complete subjective consciousness without the slightest touch and traces of this object. Pramiti bhāva is the life of all the four.

[Swami Laxmanjoo Lectures](http://www.lakshmanjooacademy.org/break-less-awareness/).

Comment: "Mantra  means  that  mental  awareness  by  which  one  feels  one's identity  with  the  highest  Reality  enshrined  in  a  mantra  and  thus saves  oneself  from  a  sense  of  separateness  and  difference  characteristic  of  the  world."