# Why some sentences written in Sanskrita are called Mantra (Powerful)?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit

Can a normal sentence be powerful ?

Why/how a Mantra have power ? Is there any proof ?

Comment: You can check my answer here. The OP asked exactly the same Q: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17653/4732

Comment: Any sentence is a combination of words and words are nothing but combinations of several alphabets. In Sanskrit there are 51 alphabets. But for the sentence (or words) to be considered powerful (in ur words) it has to be endowed with consciousness (chaitanya).Only mantras are endowed with that. Because they are spoken initially by God and heard by certain Rishi.