# Why are all mantras still in Sanskrit only even after the emergence of local languages?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit, language

If you see all marriage mantras or mantras to praise God are written only in Sanskrit, why can't those mantras be converted to local languages like hindi, telugu, tamil, malayalam etc so that everyone can understand. Imagine if a priest is pronouncing them in local languages it would be easier for everyone to understand.

Some people say that syllables are important in mantras but don't we have those syllables in other languages? God is for everyone so why are we limiting the mantras to only those who know Sanskrit. Are there any reasons for people to not know the meaning of mantras? Why is Sanskrit so famous?

EDIT: This is not duplicate as I am not asking are there any mantras in languages other than Sanskrit, it is about converting mantras to local languages

Comment: sanskrit is not a 'language' that came up like hindi/telugu etc. they are literally divine sounds. it's like asking why bees make buzzing sound, why they don't talk in english. sanskrit is the natural 'blueprint' of creation of universe, so the sounds of creation don't get transferred to other sounds (i.e. other languages)

Comment: also, Tamil Divya prabandham are of divine origin, they are called Dravida Veda, and they are recited in most Vishnu temples below Vindhya-belt of India

Comment: Shabara mantras from the Shabara Tantras are not in Sanskrit but yet those are mantras as they are spoken by Lord Shiva. See my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28414/4732

Comment: I don't think this is a dup. of the other question. Aren't you asking if Sanskrit mantras (in Devanagari script) can also be written/printed in local languages, then used for rituals? If so, you need to explain in the question why this is not a dup.

Comment: I see you made an edit clarifying your intent but you still need to click on the re-open link.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Does Hinduism allow chanting translated Vedic mantras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13874/5212) after the clarifying edit.

Comment: Question title after edit is confusing. I think you want to ask: "Are Sanskrit mantras usually transliterated to local languages?" because you are talking about [transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) and not translation. People are confusing the title for translated mantras.

Comment: probable they wont have effect in spiritual plane because each mantra have mantra drsta rishi, chandas and devata for that mantra, now chandas means no. letters in the mantra. if you change the language the no. letter is changing so different devata.. instead invoking some good God, you might actually invoke asura by chanting in different meter/chands..