# Should we pray/worship to God only in Sanskrit language?

Tags: rituals, worship, sanskrit, bhakti, language

Should we pray to gods only in the Sanskrit language and using proper mantras only? Should using other languages be avoided?

Comment: already asked .. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28381/4732

Comment: pray with your heart. the Lord is most attracted to the pure heart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kurma purana states one shouldn't praise deities with other languages.

> **Kurma Purana, Uttarabhaga, Chapter 16**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 5, lines 16/17 of the [Kāraṇā Agama](https://www.scribd.com/document/503533262/KaaranaAgama-by-R-M-Prabhulinga-Shastri-Shaiva-Bharati-Varanasi) say:

> आख्याति पूजावेलायां वैदिकं यदूचक्षणः ।
> तन्मयैवोदितमिति निर्वहत् स्वप्रयत्नतः ।।१६।।
>
> Sanskrit is the language of Siva, thus only he who speaks Sanskrit or a Vedic language may command the pooja.
>
> अवैदिकस्याख्यातॄणां निकटे नोपवेशयेत् ।
> प्रत्याख्यानं न कुर्वीत पिदध्याच्छ्रवणदूयम् ।
> नेक्षेत पूजावेलायां नरं देवि बहिष्कृतम् ।।१७।।
>
> The person who does not speak in Sanskrit may not sit near the practioner and must be ignored by the practioner.

So yes, we can only pray in Sanskrit or other Vedic languages during rituals.

Comment: What are the other Vedic languages according to Karana Agama?

Comment: If we state Sanskrit to be the only divine language, then it implies that God can't/willn't speak in any language other than Sanskrit, which goes against the established notion of the God who can't be restricted by human parameters. I personally opine that language can't be an obstruction while directly communicating with God. There are ample evidences of various sadhus from our religion conversing with God in their native tongues. Most prominent are the Alvars & Nayanmars.

Comment: @ruben2020 - the Karana Agama doesn't explain.

Comment: @অনু - yes, there are definitely many examples of what you're saying, and I don't necessarily agree with the view of this Agama. I'm only quoting it because it gives an explicit answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try it. Take your desired Sanskrit spiritual prayer and recite it sor some time. Then do the same in your native language and compare the results. You will see that prayers and mantras written in Sanskrit give better results. That's my experience.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).