# Which is the saraswati rahasya upanishad among the given two?

Tags: upanishads, saraswati

I came across two texts:

1. [The first one](https://www.facebook.com/shaktaadvaita/photos/-sarasvat%C4%AB-rahasya-upanishad-%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF-%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D-yajur-veda-bija-seed-syallble/1736866576588241/)
2. [The second one](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/sarasvati_upan.html?lang=sa)

Yet they both say that they're saraswati rahasya upanishad, and they're slightly  different. Which one is the correct one or are they different sources? (If possible please give link to a translated version of the second one as well, or perhaps the translation of the untranslated part if anyone knows sanskrit
)

P.S: Also, if anyone could tell me what lines like these mean to say:   **Of this mantra (chodayitri), Madhucchandas is the seer; Gayatri, the metre; Sarasvati, the divinity; BLUM, the seed, power and lynch-pin; consecration is with the mantra**. , It'd be really  helpful. I may not get it fully but a bit of hint if possible.

Comment: Can you provide reference to that mantra?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto , I have linked both above

Comment: The PS part means that those are the various limbs of the mantra. A mantra can have 3 limbs or even 6 or 7 limbs. Just like a human being has limbs like head, hands etc a mantra is also having limbs. Mantra and the Devata are not separate. So, a Mantra is like a living being.

Comment: You can see the following answer for understanding the limbs of mantras: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17653/4732

Comment: @Rickross , mantra is the god then? and the limbs are devtas?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference between a deity and its mantra and no limbs are not devatas. Devata itself means god. @juztcode